# Не отображаются файлы Html на хостинге

Tags: html

Залил сайт на хостинг. Некоторые файлы html не обнаруживаются, причем заметил, что с характерными для немецкого языка буквами - `ü ä` и т.д. Например:

geschäftsbedingungen.html

В чем может быть проблема? Вот шапка с заданием кодировки:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/fontawesome-all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/slick.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/slick-theme.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/animate.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/media.css">
  <title>Geschäftsfranzösisch | Lerne Französisch</title>
```

НО! На другом хостинге работает, и такие адреса (geschäftsbedingungen.html) обнаруживаются

Comment: На сервере такие файлы реально есть? Видны в ftp-клиенте?

Comment: Задание кодировки в самом файле не имеет никакого отношения к имени файла и тому, как его читает софт на хостинге.

Comment: Файлы видны. Использую WinSCP

Comment: Про не влияние кодировки - принял

Comment: Попробуйте открыть по имени ``gesch%C3%A4ftsbedingungen.html``

Comment: Попробовал - не видит, 404 всё равно

Comment: Посмотрите, какие права доступа у этих файлов.

Comment: Что происходит, если переименовать?

Comment: Если переименовываю, то находит, но таких файлов под сотню

Comment: Скорее всего, дело в правах доступа на файлы.

Comment: А как посмотреть права доступа? Что имеется ввиду? Немного не понял

Comment: В Никсах у файла есть код прав на доступ из трёх цифр от 0 до 7. Например, 755. Сейчас поищу, как в Вашем клиенте посмотреть

Comment: @Confireus Если файлы находятся при переименовании, то дело не в правах доступа, а в имени файла.

Comment: Пожалуй, да, дело не в правах.